# pivot of a 3d model outside its mesh after importing into Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-modelling

as you can see, the pivot is outside my mesh. I want to use the pivot for rotating around, for that I need to set the pivot to the real "rotating point". I know that there's the SetPivot script, but it only works with pivots inside meshes.

This mesh is part of an object which contains several meshes, I created it with Wings3d. The problem appears with .obj  and .3ds as file extension.

[image]

1.How can I fix this?

2.Is there a possibility to define a second pivot which can be used in scripts to "rotate around"(maybe a vector3 which can be set in "Designer")?

Comment: It seems you have model center wrong. I mean you probably exported it from Blender, Max.. with wrong mesh origin.

Comment: I exported it from wings3d

Comment: In Unity, you can create a parent transform and use that as a makeshift pivot. Ideally, though, you should fix this by setting a correct pivot point in your 3D modeling program.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. I recommend asking at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a youtube vide which might help. I don't know whether it will help though.

Does [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itIh8PYGP7w) help?